# SSHAuthenticationError occurs when executed perl script through windows CMD

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, cygwin

I am trying to execute a perl script which using "Net::SSH::Expect" module.

the problem that am facing is that , when i execute the script through Cygwin, it works like a charm .. but the same script when executed over windows CMD , it fails giving the below error ->

```
SSHAuthenticationError Login timed out. The input stream currently has the contents bellow: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
at /usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26/Expect.pm line 904.
```

could you please suggest what have i missed?

Comment: EMSIA? [Expect FAQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect#What-systems-does-Expect-run-on?): "Expect itself doesn't have real system dependencies, but the underlying IO::Tty needs pseudoterminals. IO::Stty uses POSIX.pm and Fcntl.pm." Then follows a note to check [IO::Tty](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Tty)

Comment: [IO::Tty](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Tty): "Windows is now supported, but ONLY under the Cygwin environment". I guess this sums up the answer to your question.

Comment: Instead of CMD, you can also try by installing the latest *PowerShell Core* (PWSH > 6.2). AFAIK PWSH in Win10 environment should now be able to use Pty's. But I must admit, I have not tested this.

Answer (score 2):

> ... Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated **because stdin is not a terminal**. ...
> *Expect.pm*

I guess the answer to this error message can be found from the documentation:

[Expect FAQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect#What-systems-does-Expect-run-on?)

> Expect itself doesn't have real system dependencies, but the underlying `IO::Tty` needs pseudoterminals. ...
>
> See `IO::Tty` for a list of verified systems.

and [IO::Tty](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Tty)

> Windows is now supported, but ONLY under the Cygwin environment, ...

Comment: Thank you stefan for the references, i will refer them.. Actually i am trying to run on eclipse as well setting the preference to cgywin (windows -> preference -> perl -> interpreter type: cygwin). which actually worked in past .. recently i had to re-install the whole setup .. and thus, came across and stuck with this error